# Castle.Windsor, ASP.NET MVC, Handling Null Resolution of Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor

Using `Castle.Windsor` in `ASP.NET MVC` (3.0) is there any way I can appropriately handle if one of my dependencies resolves null? For instance, say I have a `IMembershipService`.

```
class ServiceInstaller
{
 // ... 
 void Install( // .. )
 { 
  container.Register(
  Component
  .For<IMembershipService>()
  .ImplementedBy<MembershipService>()
  .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
  );
 }
}
```

Okay, this works great. Now, perhaps not all of my site requires a user to be logged in. Let's assume that maybe my web host's database server crashes for a few hours. In that event, things that looked into the database, or tried to call on my `ISession` might return null.

What can I do in this case? I can write `if(membershipService == null)` a hundred times over, but that seems pretty dumb. Is there a built-in solution to say *"Hey, if we have an error, do this..?"*

Comment: If your DB server crashes, your DB queries should *throw*, **never** return null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the service should never be null. If the database is down, the service should be returned nevertheless, but its methods should throw an exception, return null or some default value, depending on the semantic of the service.

Comment: Regardless, there needs to be a way to handle the situation of it not finding what it is looking for. Is there any way to set up a default behavior if the service does not return correctly?

Comment: @Stacey: can you name a concrete, plausible example?

Comment: @Mauricio: Anything has the potential to error... that's a very broad spectrum. Castle.Windsor has nothing to just handle improper resolution? Property injection, to name one. Trying to set up a property such as a logger that _is not_ log4net, which I'm not using, could resolve null if there is no file to write to due to an unforseen circumstance like a permissions error. Or trying to resolve information about a logged in user can return null on Controller destruction. In fact that's the very problem that brought me to trying to figure this out. Castle doesn't give any way to see if something

Comment: is null when it 'Releases' a controller, and as such continues to throw problems.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I don't think it is the responsibility of the container to handle such errors. The service creation should always succeed, and then it is the responsibility of the service to handle errors.

Comment: @Stacey: I agree with Antoine, this is not the responsibility of the container, and "improper resolution" sounds like something wrong with your design...

Comment: @Stacey: on logging, use NullLogger.Instance so you don't have to worry about nulls.

Comment: @Mauricio: I'm not really using logging, so I don't know what NullLogger is. I was just citing a possible example.

Comment: http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2008/06/18/logging-with-castle-windsor-the-logging-facility-and-log4net.aspx - did some quick digging, this is what I am talking about, actually. I was wondering if Castle had a default way to handle 'null' scenarios like this. The problem isn't in my construction but rather my destruction. What is `NullLogger` is the real question - it's a placeholder. It's a default instance that does nothing, and is substituted in the absence of the real thing. I was asking if there was an inherit way to assign this kind of thing, pretty much.

Comment: Basically I want to tell Castle that if it can't find a proper instance, what placeholder instance to give it. However judging from this post that doesn't seem possible. It seems the only option is to handle it per property, every single time. That's more or less what I wanted to avoid. The other option I suppose is to establish a factory, but I was kind of hoping there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks again, by the way. I think I know how to handle this situation now. What I need to do is establish null instances, and things that have a chance to return null should be implemented by a Facility instead of a simple installer.

Answer (score 0):

Ciel, [i had this problem just recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940200/castle-windsor-optional-resolution-of-component-from-a-typed-factory) and found your question while looking for the answer.

Basically you should be using a typed factory to resolve your components at runtime in your wrapping component. The factory should return a default object if there is no match regarding the component you're looking for, default object that would implement whatever behavior is needed.

In the case of your `IMembershipService`, implement a `NotCheckingMembershipService` class inheriting the interface and doing nothing and make it the default for the components that won't need it. More specific membership services can be linked to specific controllers.

To do so you must create a generic "catch-all" implementation

```
public class NotCheckingMembershipService<T>: IMembershipService<T> where T: Controller
{
}
```

And register it as the default component for an open `IMembershipService`

```
_container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(IMembershipService<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(NotCheckingMembershipService<>))
            .IsDefault());
```

Then simply register your custom membership services where needed. Resolution won't fail and you will always be able to call the interface.