# Castle.Windsor: optional resolution of component from a typed factory

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a WCF service setup with Castle.Windsor; messages arrive to a dispatcher that send them to the right component (basically a `IHandler<Message>` with message being a query).

However in some cases there is one additional before the handler can act; the message must be completed with data coming from someplace else. What i want is to check whether there exists an injector for the type of my message and if one exists, run it.

```
IInjector<Message> Injector = InjectorFactory.RetrieveInjector<Message>();
if (Injector != null)
{
    Logger.InfoFormat("IInjector<{0}> OK", input.GetType().Name);
    Injector.InjectCode(input, "Data coming from somewhere else");
}
```

The reasoning behind this is that at some future point somebody may create a plugin with a `IInjector<Message>` and I want to pick it at a future time; but at the moment it doesn't exist.

Is it possible to have a typed factory returning null when a component is not found instead of throwing a `ComponentNotFoundException`?

**EDIT**

As discussed with @Steven I will be answering my own question in order to compile what lead me to the solution and the resolution i found. First let's restate the problem

I have a WCF service basically following the structure described by Krzysztof Koźmic in [this article](http://kozmic.net/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/)

However, before calling the handlers i wanted to have an optionnal operation where the incoming message would be modified if needed.

```
private static void DoActualWork<T>(T command)
{
    IInjector<T> Injector = injectorFactory.GetInjector<T>();
    if (Injector != null) { Injector.InjectThings(command, ""); }
    var handlers = factory.GetHandlersForCommand(command);
    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        handler.Execute();
    }
}
```

I was having a problem with the injectorFactory; when i asked it to find a non-existing component it would throw a `ComponentNotFoundException`. What i would have liked is for the factory to recognize there was no component and simply return a null.

Comment: You should never return null. Instead return a 'default' or 'empty' implementation (see the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)). This way you will never have to check for null.

Comment: You might also want to consider wrapping the `IHandler<T>` with a decorator that is injected with an `IInjector<Message>`.

Comment: @Steven: i didn't think about the Null Object Pattern; it is a very good idea, but how can configure it in Castle.Windsor? Should i register a typeless IInjector<>?

Comment: I'm no Castle expert, but you can register an open generic implementation as follows: `container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IInjector<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(NullInjector<>)));`. But you'll have to try how this works when explicitly registering an implementation for a certain message.

Comment: @Steven thanks; if you could either compile your comments in an answer i'd accept it. If not i'll compile them myself for reference

Comment: I'll advice you to post an answer yourself. This allows you to add the missing pieces as well; pieces I can't add for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steven points out two ways to explore to reach a solution :

- Don't check for null, rather use a [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
- Wrap the `IHandler<T>` with a decorator and inject the IInjector in the decorator

The second option was not desirable since it would have loaded the handlers with a responsibility they didn't have to know about. Ideally I should move this injection behavior into its own independent interceptor and let it live entirely there without any other code knowing about it. I may do that later.

The first point though is the way to go. Null Object Pattern decreases the complexity of my method and leaves it much clearer than with a null check. All i have to do is create a `NopInjector` class and declare it as the default value for the factory.

**Don't** try to create an injector depending on a base object:

```
public class NopInjector : IInjector<object>
{
    public void InjectStuff(object target, string stuff) { }
}
```

Rather create a generic injector and register it as an open generic component

```
public class NopInjector<T> : IInjector<T>
{
    public void InjectStuff(T target, string stuff) { }
}

// registration
_container.Register(
            Component.For(typeof(IInjector<>))
            .ImplementedBy(typeof(NopInjector<>))
            .IsDefault());
_container.Register(
            Classes
            .FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
            .BasedOn(typeof(IInjector<>))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces());
```

Now if Castle.Windsor can resolve a specific `IInjector<Command>` it will, else it will return the `NopInjector`. No more null check:

```
private static void DoActualWork<T>(T command)
{
    injectorFactory.GetInjector<T>().InjectThings(command, "");
    // calling handlers...
}
```